# Extract and decode stringified byte string in python?

Tags: python, substring

I have string like this that has a stringified byte substring inside of it as follows:

`some_string = "b'Hurricane Mitch\\n'"`

What is the best way to extract the nested b' string so that I can decode it properly in utf8?

Comment: How did you end up with this data? I would rather fix that.

Comment: I didn't generate it, it was provided to me and the original doesn't exist anymore so unfortunately it's not an option.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward approach (that's still more powerful than you need, but probably not a security risk) is [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
from ast import literal_eval
some_string = "b'Hurricane Mitch\\n'"
literal_eval(some_string).decode('utf-8') # 'Hurricane Mitch\n'
```